# CORS issue between subdomains in Laravel5

Tags: apache, .htaccess, laravel-5, cors

I built an API on Laravel5 and had CORS issues on localhost in development enviroment, so I developed this middleware and used on the API's routes, which solved the issue:

```
class Cors
{
    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $response = $next($request)
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://zekrishna.com')
        ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

        return  $response;
    }
}
```

When I depolyed the app the CORS problems started again. I used the same server to host the API and front-end, where the front-end is on the server's root and the API on a subdomain.

Here's my .htacess on `public/`:

```
...

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Headers "origin, x-requested-with, content-type"
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Methods "PUT, GET, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS"
</IfModule>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load
>   http://api.zekrishna.com/api/agenda/?api_token=9BuDRcUxUbl9jW2FDnMxToijR8plDsT4xkVRg7m3AThJHJWXqsNSOGy94x1B.
>   Redirect from
>   'http://api.zekrishna.com/api/agenda/?api_token=9BuDRcUxUbl9jW2FDnMxToijR8plDsT4xkVRg7m3AThJHJWXqsNSOGy94x1B'
>   to
>   'http://api.zekrishna.com/api/agenda?api_token=9BuDRcUxUbl9jW2FDnMxToijR8plDsT4xkVRg7m3AThJHJWXqsNSOGy94x1B'
>   has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'
>   header is present on the requested resource. Origin
>   'http://zekrishna.com' is therefore not allowed access.

**EDIT**

I deleted my .htaccess rules and changed my middleware: (due to duplicated Access-Control-Allow-Origin on response header)

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $response = $next($request)
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://zekrishna.com')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true')
    ->header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');

    return  $response;
}
```

I'm using jQuery `$.ajax` method to call the API

```
const API_TOKEN = '9BuDRcUxUbl9jW2FDnMxToijR8plDsT4xkVRg7m3AThJHJWXqsNSOGy94x1B';
const API = 'http://api.zekrishna.com/api';

...

$.ajax({
    url: API + '/agenda/',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    data: {api_token: API_TOKEN}
})
.done(setConcerts)
```

Answer (score 0):

I can access this via an HTTP GET, and there appears to be two headers sent. Your htaccess is setting one, as is your middleware.

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.zekrishna.com/api/agenda?api_token=9BuDRcUxUbl9jW2FDnMxToijR8plDsT4xkVRg7m3AThJHJWXqsNSOGy94x1B. The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'http://zekrishna.com, *', but only one is allowed. Origin is therefore not allowed access

Is it possible that your local environment htaccess isn't kicking in?

Comment: I removed the .htaccess rules and kept the middleware, but the issue continues...

Answer (score 0):

I removed the last slash on my request and worked!
The server was redirecting and these request was not allowed.

Before:

```
$.ajax({
    url: API + '/agenda/',
    ...
})
```

then:

```
$.ajax({
    url: API + '/agenda',
    ...
})
```